# Update Interval for Location Service Android

Tags: android, service, locationlistener

I am writing a Location Service, with a update Interval to send the Location updates to the server.
But I trying to update this interval variable in the service via user input(`AlertDialog`). It works perfectly fine when hard coded.

I am using this code to get the interval variable from the `AlertDialog` class, in the `onCreate()` of the service.

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    final boolean tr=true;
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {

                while (tr) {

                    //check your static variable here
                    updateInterval=ShowCurInterval.loadCurInterval(getApplicationContext());//ShowCur Interval is the Alert Dialog calss
                    Log.d(" INTERVAL ","Interval "+ updateInterval);
                  try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                }
              }}
               ).start();

      startLocationListener(updateInterval);
}
```

And I can also see the new updateInterval value in Log ( which is added from the Alert Dialog). But `requestLocationUpdates()` still uses the pre defined updateInterval value.

Here is the startLocationListener() method:

```
public void startLocationListener(int updateInterval) {
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, updateInterval, updateDistance, locListener);
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Loclistener started, Updatetime: " + updateInterval);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UPDATE INTERVAL"+updateInterval,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
    preInterval = updateInterval;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how can I update this variable?

@binW
Edited part with exception:

```
    Handler mhandler = new Handler ();
       mhandler.postDelayed( new Runnable(){

          public void run(){
              Looper.prepare();

              updateInterval=SingletonManager.getInstance().loadCurInterval(getApplicationContext());
              SingletonManager.getInstance().saveCurInterval(getApplicationContext(), updateInterval);
              startLocationListener(updateInterval); 
              Log.d(" INTERVAL ","Interval "+ updateInterval);
              //startChecking();


          }
       }, 2000);
```

Exception:

```
04-17 03:18:55.250: E/AndroidRuntime(2146): java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: what is happening? Is it working with previous update rate only?

Comment: @raju Hello..Yes it works only with the previous update rate. updateInterval is a global variable with value 10000(millisec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling startLocationListener() in onCreate() and not in the thread that you created for getting the new value of updateInterval. But the call to startLocationListener(updateInterval); gets executed before the new thread executes and hence you get the old value of updateInterval. I believe you should change your code to following:

```
public Handler handler;
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            startLocationListener(updateInterval);
        }
    };

    final boolean tr=true;
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             while (tr) {
                //check your static variable here
                updateInterval=ShowCurInterval.loadCurInterval(getApplicationContext());//ShowCur Interval is the Alert Dialog calss
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                Log.d(" INTERVAL ","Interval "+ updateInterval);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                }
              }}
        ).start();
}
```

Comment: 04-16 08:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(13728): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: And also the startLocationListener() is not started.

Comment: startLocationListener() is started only if it is outside the thread..Can you please tell me what I should do..

Comment: use a handler to start the location listener in main activity thread instead of the new thread you are creating. I have modified the answer to do exactly this. Also, I must mention, I dont like use of Thread in this context. This could all be done with handler only.

Comment: thank you for ur answer...now I can start the location listener..But the updateInterval value is still not updated. Could you please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: I edited my question. I also tried using only the Handler. But I get runtime exception.